# Visual Studio Development > Visual Studio Integrate

Tags: vspackage

I created a basic VSPackage and it is displayed in Tool Menu Option of experimental instance of VS.

Question 1: Once experimental instance of VS opened custom VSPackage should be disabled if user opens any solution file then only it should enable. example : File (Menu)--- Close Solution (SubMenu)

Question 2: After open any solution file, then custom Package inside Tool Menu is clicked i want to show that particular solution file path in alert.

Any tips on these questions are very helpful.

Thanks in advance,

SABARINATHAN.T

Answer (score 0):

1. To enable/disable based on the opening of a solution listen to the [OnAfterOpenSolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb141418(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the [IVsSolutionEvents3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolutionEvents3(v=vs.120).aspx) interface. You should be aware that this event triggers immediately after the solution opens and doesn't wait until it's completely loaded.
2. Example to get the solution path:

   `DTE dte = (DTE) GetService(typeof(DTE));
   string solutionPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);`